# MovieClipEditor : Load frames using a script when filesname are not enumerated

Tags: python, tracking, masking, movie-clip-editor

Got a folder of image files from time-lapse imaging which need to be read into the *MovieClipEditor*.

The filenames are not enumerated following blender's convention, and there's value in not modifying these.

The goal is to process the time-lapse images in Blender, namely apply [Motion Tracking & Masking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/movie_clip/index.html) .

How could these be read to a `MovieClip`?

According to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210637/133653, it cannot be done.

My current Workaround is to create symbolic links to the source image files, and rename the links, so as these could be opened using the *MovieClipEditor*.
Would be great to have an alternative, internal within Blender and `BPy`-API.

This post, [blender.exchange best-way-to-load-image-from-list-python-script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135957/133653), may be a good starting point. Could `bpy.data.images` be added to a `MovieClip` ?

Comment: Can you use a 3rd party app to assemble the images into video file that you could the load?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, these could be compiled into an .mkv file. For my needs the symbolic links workaround is a better fit -- hardly takes space and time to create; the symbolic links show reference to the source files, so it is somewhat self-documenting for later reference.

Comment: I think you'll find that to be less fragile than the extra steps you'll have to take to do it in Blender in python.